# Git: how to specify file names containing octal notation on the command line

Tags: git, encoding, notation, octal

For non-ASCII characters in file names, Git will output them in *octal notation*. For example:

```
> git ls-files
"\337.txt"
```

If such a byte sequence does not represent a legal encoding (for the command line's current encoding), I'm not able to enter the corresponding String on command line. How can I still invoke Git commands on these files? Obviously, using the String which is displayed by `git ls-files` does not work:

```
> git rm "\337.txt"
fatal: pathspec '337.txt' did not match any files
```

Tested on Windows, with msysgit 1.7.10 (git version 1.7.10.msysgit.1)

Comment: See [How to make Git properly display UTF-8 encoded pathnames in the console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827239/how-to-make-git-properly-display-utf-8-encoded-pathnames-in-the-console-window).
`git config --global core.quotepath off`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Bash, you can use [`printf`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/printf/) for this kind of purpose:

```
$ printf "\337.txt"
▒.txt

$ git rm `printf "\337.txt"`  # this would pass the awkward filename to git
```

The problem is, obviously, that the shell doesn't perform octal escaping, neither does git. But `printf` does.

---

Also, `echo -e` can do octal escaping:

```
$ echo -e '\0337.txt'
▒.txt
```

But that usage is a bit discouraged, you should prefer `printf` where you can.

Comment: How would I use that in combination with Git commands? What if I have msysgit installed?

Comment: @mstrap I hope that msys provides a `printf` utility, because it's a standard posix one. You should try if it's available to you. Also see edit.

Comment: The printf-version works perfectly from within msysgit's bash. Thanks!

Comment: eg: `  git ls-tree --name-only $GIT_COMMIT |  xargs -0  printf  | xargs -I  files mv  files $d `