# Strange name in git file

Tags: java, git

Working on a Java project with Eclipse I found some strange git behavior. When trying to commit files from my terminal (in zsh) git showed up with this:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
new file:   "src/com/sierisimo/app\bfragments/FragmentMenu.java"


Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    deleted:    "src/com/sierisimo/app\bfragments/FragmentMenu.java"
```

And I found a [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250633/remove-a-file-with-a-strange-name-from-git)

But they are talking about octal numbers and "**\b**" doesn't look like an octal number...

What do you suggest?

Comment: I assume you would expect a `/` instead?

Comment: Yes, it should be a `/` but I don't know where or when it became that character

Comment: Is `\b` possibly a replacement for a space character? Is the subdirectory named "app fragments" with a space?

Comment: Nope, the `\b` was suppossed to be a `/` but it already fix it, I'll give my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the thing was very strange, but the thing get solved by itself, first I added every thing that wasn't on that directory.

Then when all was ready except for that directory for commiting, I just moved to

```
src/com/sierisimo/
```

and then just added the full directory:

```
git add .
```

this added the directory with the correct name:

```
src/com/sierisimo/app/fragments/FragmentMenu.java
```

but the thing that annoys me was: what if I have thing that I didn't wanted to commit on subdirectories...

Well, at least I was able to commit my changes. If anyone gets a better ansewr to this, please provide it.